# Google Sheets, Nested IF statements

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IF(F7="Unchained","975",=IF(F7="Infernal","520",=IF(F7="Golden","490")))
```

Trying to check the cell above F8 for certain strings, then displaying a value based on the string. But I keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have the formatting/syntax correct. Check my answer bellow

Comment: Also, are you going to copy the formula later on?

Comment: I will copy the formula later on with different values and strings. Thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `=` signs in the nested part of the formula that you have typed. Also, you can remove the speech marks (quotation marks) `" "` from the numbers. This is because numbers aren't `Strings`. They can be written without speech marks around them.